# My unity game seems to be using more FPS than I limit to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make an fps limiter for a game so it would use as little of my pc resources so I could run it in the back ground, but it isn't limiting. Allowing it to use up to 30% of my cpu.
Here is my code, is there anything I should do?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FPSLimiter : MonoBehaviour
{

    int targetfps = 30;

    void Start()
    {
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
        Application.targetFrameRate = targetfps;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Application.targetFrameRate != targetfps)
        {
            Application.targetFrameRate = targetfps;
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: are you testing on editor or build? Editor do not limit the fps I think..Try to make a build and print the fps, then tell us the difference between the target and the current build pls

Comment: The build and the editor both were above the limited FPS